# Как в списке поменять конкретные символы по индексу

Tags: python

Задаю вопрос чисто для понимания своего, у меня список

```
['dfargagaga', 'gdfgsagrdsg', 'gagadgadgddr']
```

В каждом есть r, вот как мне через цикл или еще как поменять r на другой символ, при этом изменения должны коснуться все строк в списке.

Тоже самое интересует со словарями как в этом примере:

```
{name:'123', int:35523}
```

Как мне тут у каждого поменять 2 на 9 к примеру?

Comment: С чем конкретно проблема? Заменить символ? Найти r? Пройти по элементами списка?

Answer (score 1):

Для списка:

```
lis  = ['dfargagaga', 'gdfgsagrdsg', 'gagadgadgddr']
for i in lis:
    word = ''
    for symbol in i:
        if symbol == 'r':
            symbol = 'new'   
        word+=symbol
    lis[lis.index(i)] = word
print(lis)
```

Для словаря:

```
o = {'name':'123', 'int':35523}
for i in o:
    word = ''
    for symbol in str(o[i]):
        if symbol == '2':
            symbol = 'NEW'
        word+=symbol
    o[i] = word
print(o)
```

Comment: есть специально обученая функция, называется str.replace()

Comment: Мне почему-то казалась, что эта функция способна заменять только отдельно стоящие слова

Comment: да не, заменяет последовательности символов на последовательности символов. Длина последовательностей и наличие в них пробелов и других спецзнаков не имеют значения.

Comment: lis[lis.index(i)] = word что оно делает?

Comment: Заменяет слово, в котором нужно было заменить буквы, на другое слово с замененными